# How to add libraries in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I will be going to university next year and I am trying to learn myself how to program in C#.
I started with a new project on visual studio, and I pasted the program below from my textbook in a empty project.
As you can see, in the first 2 sentences, there are a couple of libraries used that visual studio doesn't recognize. What am I doing wrong here?

complete beginner btw.

[the pasted program from my textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ8mE.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and don't post pictures of code, post the code instead

Comment: right click 'add reference' on the project. or ctrl+Q, "add reference"

Comment: You should learn C# with tutorials. There are some good tutorials on Youtube or on Pluralsight.

Comment: and if the book didnt tell you how to do that then get a different book

Comment: I recommend using the Microsoft Virtual Academy - they have lots of excellent free courses on C# ("C# Fundamentals") written and presented by really good lecturers. I'll have to agree to close this question because its not compatible with SO, but hope this info will be useful for a beginner programmer. We all start somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, you have a **solution** and **projects**.

- Solution: Contains one or more projects
- Project: Contains the source code for each project

If you have a solution with two projects, you can add one project to the other project with:

1. Right click on "Add Reference"
2. Click on the checkbox for the second project
3. Click on OK

If you want to follow these steps, you need a **project** not only a .cs file!

---

**UPDATE**

But I think, that this is not your problem.. Based on your image, you forget the namespace.

Add:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
```

under the last using statement and:

```
}
```

on the bottom, after the last `}`

Your classes must be placed in a namespace!

Look at this tutorial: [C# Namespace Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_namespaces.htm)